# Creating multiple Outlook appointments from one line of data

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The below creates an appointment in Outlook from my Excel data - is there any way to create multiple appointments, rather than what the below does which just updates a single appointment? I'd need 3 different appointments (dates for each in column number 33, 38 and 43), the code I have just makes a single appointment and updates until the last date.

```
Sub ResolveName()

Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, _
    r As Long, i As Long, wb As ThisWorkbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = wb.Sheets("Licences")
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")


    Dim SharedMailboxEmail As String

    SharedMailboxEmail = "xxx@xxx.com"  

    Set outSharedName = myNamespace.CreateRecipient(SharedMailboxEmail)
    Set outCalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(outSharedName, olFolderCalendar)
    Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("DTS Streetworks")
    myRecipient.Resolve



    r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To r
        With Cells(i, 5)

         If myRecipient.Resolved And .Value = "TTRO" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
    With outappointment
                    .Subject = "Send Notice of Intent - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                    .Start = ES.Cells(i, 33) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                    .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    .Save
    End With

    With outappointment
                    .Subject = "Send Notice of Making - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                    .Start = ES.Cells(i, 38) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                    .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    .Save
    End With

With outappointment
                    .Subject = "Send Full Order - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                    .Start = ES.Cells(i, 43) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                    .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    .Save
    End With
    End If
    End With
    Next i

    Set OL = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ES = Nothing

End Sub

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
    CalendarFolder.Display
End Sub
```

UPDATE -

As per comment stating new requirements, code below:

```
Sub ResolveNameTTRO()
    Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, r As Long, i As Long, wb As ThisWorkbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = wb.Sheets("Licences")
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim SharedMailboxEmail As String

    SharedMailboxEmail = "xxx@xxx.com"
    Set outSharedName = myNamespace.CreateRecipient(SharedMailboxEmail)
    Set outCalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(outSharedName, olFolderCalendar)
    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("DTS Streetworks")
    myRecipient.Resolve

    r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To r
        With Cells(i, 5)
          If myRecipient.Resolved And .Value = "TTRO" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
             Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
             With outappointment
                             .Subject = "Send Notice of Intent - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                             .Start = ES.Cells(i, 33) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                             .ReminderSet = True
                             .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                             .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                             .Save
             End With

             Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
             With outappointment
                             .Subject = "Send Notice of Making - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                             .Start = ES.Cells(i, 38) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                             .ReminderSet = True
                             .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                             .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                             .Save
             End With

             Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
             With outappointment
                             .Subject = "Send Full Order - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                             .Start = ES.Cells(i, 43) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                             .ReminderSet = True
                             .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                             .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                             .Save
             End With

             If myRecipient.Resolved And .Value = "Section 50" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
             Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
             With outappointment
                             .Subject = "Send licence - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                             .Start = ES.Cells(i, 54) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                             .ReminderSet = True
                             .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                             .Body = "Send licence to " + ES.Cells(i, 10).Value
                             .Save
             End With

             If myRecipient.Resolved And .Value = "Mobile Plant" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
             Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
             With outappointment
                             .Subject = "Send licence - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                             .Start = ES.Cells(i, 54) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                             .ReminderSet = True
                             .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                             .Body = "Send licence to " + ES.Cells(i, 10).Value
                             .Save
             End With
             End If
             End With

    Next i

    Set OL = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ES = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The format of the site encourages one question per post so there can be an accepted answer. Delete the edit and ask a separate on-topic question. That way you may accept an answer there if you wish. You cannot accept two answers on the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to create 3 appointments, you need to move `Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)` inside the loop and do it 3 times.  The revised code illustrates this idea.

```
Sub ResolveName()
    Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, r As Long, i As Long, wb As ThisWorkbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = wb.Sheets("Licences")
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim SharedMailboxEmail As String

    SharedMailboxEmail = "xxx@xxx.com"
    Set outSharedName = myNamespace.CreateRecipient(SharedMailboxEmail)
    Set outCalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(outSharedName, olFolderCalendar)
    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("DTS Streetworks")
    myRecipient.Resolve

    r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To r
        With Cells(i, 5)
          If myRecipient.Resolved And .Value = "TTRO" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
             Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
             With outappointment
                             .Subject = "Send Notice of Intent - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                             .Start = ES.Cells(i, 33) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                             .ReminderSet = True
                             .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                             .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                             .Save
             End With

             Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
             With outappointment
                             .Subject = "Send Notice of Making - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                             .Start = ES.Cells(i, 38) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                             .ReminderSet = True
                             .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                             .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                             .Save
             End With

             Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
             With outappointment
                             .Subject = "Send Full Order - " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value + " " + ES.Cells(i, 12).Value
                             .Start = ES.Cells(i, 43) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                             .ReminderSet = True
                             .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                             .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                             .Save
             End With
          End If
        End With
    Next i

    Set OL = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ES = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For each time specified in the Excel row you just need to repeat the following call:

```
Set outappointment = outCalendarFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
```

Comment: I'm now trying to make it create appointments based on the cell value - if the value is `TTRO` as above it will create the 3 appointments which now works, however I then also want it to continue to check the values and make an appointment on a date in column BB (54). Tried the amended code in original post but no luck?